# c++ priority_queue initialization. Why can we ignore const Compare&

Tags: c++, priority-queue, min-heap, max-heap

```
class Star {
 public:
  // The distance between this star to the Earth.
  double distance() const { return sqrt(x_ * x_ + y_ * y_ + z_ * z_); }

  bool operator<(const Star& s) const { return distance() < s.distance(); }

  int ID_;
  double x_, y_, z_;
};



priority_queue<Star, vector<Star>> max_heap;
```

Look at last line. This is priority_queue max_heap's initialization. Why it ignore the c++  const Compare&.
I thought it would be

```
priority_queue<Star, vector<Star>, Star> max_heap;
```

It looks different as below one, which I understand.

```
class mycomparison
{
  bool reverse;
public:
  mycomparison(const bool& revparam=false)
    {reverse=revparam;}
  bool operator() (const int& lhs, const int&rhs) const
  {
    if (reverse) return (lhs>rhs);
    else return (lhs<rhs);
  }
};

int main ()
{
  int myints[]= {10,60,50,20};

  std::priority_queue<int> first;
  std::priority_queue<int> second (myints,myints+4);
  std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int> >
                            third (myints,myints+4);
  // using mycomparison:
  typedef std::priority_queue<int,std::vector<int>,mycomparison> mypq_type;

  mypq_type fourth;                       // less-than comparison
  mypq_type fifth (mycomparison(true));   // greater-than comparison

  return 0;
}
```

I read this page:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/priority_queue/

cannot get the definitive definition of priority_queue constructor paradigm.

**Also, Why sometimes it overloads "<" as comparator. Sometimes overloads "()" as comparator?**
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default comparison is `std::less< Star >` which will call the `operator <` you have defined.

Template type parameters can have deault arguments, just like function parameters. It's the same with the default container type, which is `std::vector< Star >`. Actually you can write the declaration simply as

```
priority_queue<Star> max_heap;
```

---

> Also, Why sometimes it overloads "<" as comparator. Sometimes overloads "()" as comparator?

The comparator is always a Callable object, that is, a function or function-like object (functor). The things to be compared are passed using function-call notation with parentheses. `std::less` is the adaptor which makes a given `bool operator< (T, T)` overload accessible as the member `operator()` of a functor.

For example, here is how `std::less` may be implemented:

```
template< typename T >
struct less {
    bool operator () ( T const & lhs, T const & rhs ) const
        { return lhs < rhs; } // Calls Star::operator < ()
};
```

`std::less` is actually an object type, and such an object is actually stored inside the `priority_queue`. Its `operator()` is what makes the comparison. The call to your `operator <` happens this way.

Comment: "std::less is the adaptor which makes a given bool operator< (T, T) overload accessible as the member operator() of a functor."  This sentence is hard to understand. Ｓorry, English is not my native lang.

Comment: @NoName Added some clarification.